# Get CPU model name on Linux without parsing /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: c, linux

I want to get CPU name on linux using C without parsing `/proc/cpuinfo`, I actually want the code that writes the data to `/proc/cpuinfo`, Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with parsing cpuinfo?

Comment: The code that writes to `/proc/cpuinfo` will be in the kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/cpuinfo` is not a real file, it only exists as part of the `procfs` file system (which is virtual). The code responsible for producing this virtual file is part of the Linux kernel. See [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/cpuinfo.c).

For x86 CPUs for example, you can have a look at how this file is generated [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/proc.c).

Answer (score 0):

As dreamlax already mentions, cpuinfo is a file provided by the virtual filesystem `procfs`, hence a read system call is the way to read the information directly from the kernel.

There is also the system call `uname` which provides a hardware identifier (machine)...